# PHP Video database OUTPUT

Tags: php, database, video, output

I want to output my videos which are listed in the database. Everything is working but I can't see all of the entries in the database. Here is and pseudeoutput:

```
Video4 Video3 Video2 Video1
```

When I have 5 entries in the database the output is like:

```
Video5 Video4 Video3 Video2
Video1
```

But now where my problem starts is, when I have more than 5 entries, I can't see the first entry in the output (on the website). The output is like this:

```
Video6 Video5 Video4 Video3
Video2
```

and Video1 is deleted for some reason and I also can't see it when I am pressing on F12 (Chrome).

This is how my database looks like:

```
id   description   filename    fileextension
1      Test1      Video1.mp4        mp4
2      Test2      Video2.mp4        mp4
3      Test3      Video3.mp4        mp4
4      Test4      Video4.mp4        mp4
5      Test5      Video5.mp4        mp4
6      Test6      Video6.mp4        mp4
```

And the output code:

```
<?php

                    $result= mysql_query( "SELECT description, filename, fileextension FROM video ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5" ) 
                    or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error()); 

                    echo "<div class='scrollbar'>";
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
                        echo "<div class='responsive'><div class='gallery'>"; 
                        $videos_field= $row['filename'];
                        $video_show= "Uploads/videos/$videos_field";
                        $descriptionvalue= $row['description'];
                        $fileextensionvalue= $row['fileextension'];
                        echo "<div class='desc'><font face=arial size=5 color=#CFB53B />$descriptionvalue</font></div>";
                        echo "<a><video controls><source src='$video_show' type='video/$fileextensionvalue'>Your browser does
                        not support the video tag.</video></a>";
                        echo "</div></div>"; 
                    } 
                    echo "</div>";

            ?>
```

and some css:

```
div.scrollbar{
                width:100%;
                height:720px;
                overflow:auto;
            }   

            div.gallery {
                margin-left: 8px;
                margin-right: 2px;
                margin-top: 40px;
            }

            div.gallery video {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }

            div.desc {
                padding: 15px;
                text-align: center;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }

            div.desc:hover {
                border: 1px solid #CFB53B;
            }

            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
```

The output from 1 to 5 is ok after the 6th entry I can't see the first one anymore. When I have 7 entries in the database, Video1 and Video2 will be deleted.

I need your help guys..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `LIMIT 5` clause from

```
$result= mysql_query( "SELECT description, filename, fileextension FROM video ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5" )
```

to get more results. This clause does just what it's name suggests - limits result set.

Comment: @DrSyntrax accept the answer if it helped you(tick icon to the left of the answer).